# Conditional Column/DAX

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, dax

How can I add a conditional column or DAX for column generation? If the year of birth is within the range of 1960-1980 it will flash (baby boomers) 1980-2000 (Gen X) 2000 to 2020 (Millenials). I'm new in power bi appreciate your help guys, Thanks! please see the snip below of my error formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGrPc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom column with this code:

```
=

    if [#"Year "] >= 1960 and [#"Year "] <= 1979 then "Baby Boomers"
    else if [#"Year "] >= 1980 and [#"Year "] <= 1999 then "Gen X"
    else if [#"Year "] >= 2000 and [#"Year "] <= 2020 then "Millenials"
    else "No Generation"
```

You can change the rule, like >= 1960 and < 1980, adapting to what do you want.